# PHP undelivered mail

Tags: phpmailer

trying sending some mail using function **mail()**

```
$passage_ligne = "\r\n";
$boundary = "-----=".md5(rand());

$headers  = 'From:'.$nom.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$nom.' <'.$email.'>'.$passage_ligne;  
$headers .= "Message-ID:<".time()." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">".$passage_ligne;
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$passage_ligne; 
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$passage_ligne;
$headers.= "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"$boundary\"".$passage_ligne;

if(file_exists($file))
{
  $file_type = filetype($file);
  $file_size = filesize($file);

  $handle = fopen($file, 'r') or die('File '.$file.'can t be open');
  $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
  $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
  $f = fclose($handle);

  $corps = '--'.$boundary."\r\n";
  $corps .= 'Content-type:'.$file_type.';name='.$file."\r\n";
  $corps .= 'Content-transfer-encoding:base64'."\r\n";
  $corps .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$file."'\r\n";
  $corps .= $content."\r\n";
 }
```

In the undelivered message, it says:

> > Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=xxx-xxx.com type=A: Host not found

Can't see whats wrong please?

Comment: And HELLO world :)

Comment: Either your host name is wrong, or your DNS is broken.

Comment: I were using a wrong email x) It's OK now ^^